# How to swap bits at specified position from uint256 in solidity

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to swap bits in uint256 by their position. For example, I would like to swap bits at position 0-4 with bits at position 5-9. How could this be achieved in solidity?

I know that bitwise operations should be done, but I'm not sure which one.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it as following:

```
function swapBits(uint256 _source) pure public returns (uint256) {
    // Get first 5 bits and shift them left by 5 bits
    uint16 bits1 = uint16(_source & 0x1F) << 5;

    // Get second 5 bits
    uint16 bits2 = uint16(_source >> 5) & 0x1F;

    return _source & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC00 | bits1 | bits2;
}
```